# Cannot read files created from cygwin shell

Tags: bash, vim, cygwin

So, I've got fileA.py on my (Win7) system.  I can open it up and edit it (with gVim) just fine.

In bash, I run `cp fileA.py fileB.py`.

At this point, I am unable to open fileB.py with gVim and instead get a [Permission Denied] error.

Even though I cannot open it in gVim, I am still able to `cat fileB.py` to read its contents.

I then run `stat -c "%a %n" *.py` and I see that both fileA.py and fileB.py have identical (bash) permissions.  But one can be opened, and the other cannot.
    70 fileA.py
    70 fileB.py

In order to move forward, I can `chmod 777 fileB.py`.  This will then allow me to edit it in gVim.  Of course, my permissions are now set to 777, which is not ideal.

I only get this problem with files created from my cygwin shell (bash).  If I go to Windows Explorer and copy the files, I have no such problems.

Comment: Sounds like a permissions/ownership issue. Did you try regenerating your /etc/group and /etc/passwd?

Comment: No.  How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your Cygwin permissions don't match your Windows permissions. As with *nix systems you want to be sure that your `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` match up with your Windows credentials. Sometimes you need to rebuild one or both files.

At a basic level this rebuilds the files but it may not do everything you need:

```
mkpasswd -l [-d] > /etc/passwd
mkgroup  -l [-d] > /etc/group
```

`-l` works with the local system and `-d` pulls domain information. You can pull a lot of accounts if you are on a domain. It's best to read the cygwin documentation for [mkpasswd](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/mkpasswd.html) and [mkgroup](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/mkgroup.html) to help narrow the scope.

After regenerating you may need to adjust the ownership of your Cygwin files.